# GPFlow - multiple output kernels and choice of inducing points for multi-dimensional input data

Tags: gpflow

What is the best way to choose inducing points in a multiple-output GP model where in the input data is multi-dimensional?

I have `370` observations with `847` dimensions (each observation is a spectrum) with all values in the range `0..1`. I have `10` response variables I wish to predict per observation.

I have modelled the data with independent GPs, and have shown that my data is able to be modelled, and so now want to create a multi-output model with separate independent multi-output kernels and shared independent inducing variables.

From the [GPFlow example](https://gpflow.github.io/GPflow/develop/notebooks/advanced/multioutput.html#2.-Separate-independent-MOK-and-shared-independent-inducing-variables), I think I need an inducing point array of shape `(M, 847)`, where `M` is the number of inducing points.

What is the best way in which I can choose values for the `847`-length dimension required? The example is simply `M` values in the range `min(X)..max(X)`, which works when `X` has one dimension.